# Arrays difference and elements partially equal

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to compare two arrays excluding elements partially equal.

I have reached the following result:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
```

The desired result is:

```
21 22 23 24 25
```

#### Attempt:

```
$aa = array("1 2 3 4 5", "6 7 8 9 10", "11 12 13 14 15", "16 17 18 19 20", "21 22 23 24 25");
$bb = array("1 2", "6 7 8", "11 12 13 14", "16 17 18 19 20");
$final = array_diff($aa, $bb);
print_r($final)
```

Comment: You forgot the code. Also, this question is really unclear.

Comment: Thank you. There was a problem with the code. I have simplified the code with the aim to get a suggestion. I can not fine a solution. I have tried array_diff, preg_match and a number of others, but i can not find the correct instruction.

Comment: Does your array diff must be align? as `$aa[0]` against `$bb[0]` and so on? or you want to check each index in `$aa` against all `$bb` elements?

Comment: You need to clarify why 3 4 5 9 
 10 and 15 isn't part of the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_grep in order to not have to do any manipulation the the data.
This will regex to see what is matching and then you just use array_diff.

```
$aa = array("1 2 3 4 5", "6 7 8 9 10", "11 12 13 14 15", "16 17 18 19 20", "21 22 23 24 25");
$bb = array("1 2", "6 7 8", "11 12 13 14", "16 17 18 19 20");

$exclude = [];
foreach($bb as $b){
    $exclude = array_merge($exclude, preg_grep("/^". preg_quote($b) . "/", $aa));
}
$final = array_diff($aa, $exclude);

print_r($final);
```

https://3v4l.org/XI9Jd

Comment: Notice OP doesn't want `3 4 5` as part of them (`1 2`) is in `$bb`

Comment: @dWinder that makes no sense. OP needs to clarify then

Comment: Tks. This example does not work for my purposes. My aim is compare each element in array $aa and exclude it if partially equal. e.g. "1 2" in $bb excludes "1 2 3 4 5" and so on. Considering my example I would reach the following result "21 22 23 24 25". All other elements of array $aa should be excluded.

Comment: So if one subitem of $bb is matching in $aa then all subitems in $aa is discarded?

Comment: sorry for my late reply. I had some tests. The solution above mentioned works but just in theory. Indeed, my aim is different. It is not enough to discard a subitems in $aa if one subitem of $bb match. I would compare each element of the array in $aa with groups of two, three or four numbers of $bb (not just one) and discard a subitem if partially mach with $bb. Maybe I could use array_diff with jolly characters?